# jquery ui dialog - open when page loads if browser is ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialogue but need it to open as soon as the page is loaded if the browser is ie (Internet Explorer). I have made the dialogue, but cannot seem to find anywhere in the API Documentation to open a dialogue on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach a normal [`$(window).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) handler but wrap it in a [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div id="ie-dialog">...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#ie-dialog').dialog();
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

You could also wait until the DOM is ready if you need it:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div id="ie-dialog">...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ie-dialog').dialog();
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    }
});
```

You can find more in [documentation for jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)